# JSF not showing data from database

Tags: mysql, jsf

I'm trying  to show data from mysql database in JSF, but nothing show up. Getting page with table without data. I'm using  http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsf/database/viewdata.html tutorial

**index.xhtml**  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>index.xhtml</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h1>JSF 2.0 View Data From The Database Table Example</h1>

        <h:dataTable value="#{UserBean.getUserList()}" var="u" border="1">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    User ID
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.userID}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.name}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Address
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.address}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Created Date
                </f:facet>
                    #{u.created_date}
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not complete, can not answer unless you Provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's hard to answer. But you can try: `#{userBean.userList}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've just mistyped the managed-bean's name in your view when using within the `<h:dataTable>`'s tag. You should render its first letter lowercase to enable the proper use, i.e from `value="#{UserBean.getUserList()}"` to `value="#{userBean.getUserList()}"`.

Comment: After i change value "{UserBean.getUserList()} to "userbean.getUserList()} getting following error

Comment: Just make the 1st letter lowercase with conserving the remaining name as it's: `userBean.getUserList()`.